# Which house / safe storage chest is closest to a fast travel destination?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, what house or safe storage chest is the closest in travel time from a fast travel location? Preferably there should be no loading screens between the fast travel location and a chest to dump stuff.

I am currently using the Riverside Shack south of Windhelm which is reasonable close though still annoying for lack of containers and drafts. (And may not be safe.)

Note: The place doesn't need to be free, I've quite a bit of money. I'm looking for the overall most efficient / fast access house.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I really don't see how you can beat Breezehome in Whiterun for the combination of features and time.

While there is a loading screen, it's extremely fast even on my slow laptop (which is below the minimum specs for Skyrim in several ways) and it's just a few steps from the fast travel location.

There are two sacks on the shelf right by the door you can reach without moving once inside.

There are plenty of other containers for sorted, more long term storage. You can get the "Well Rested" buff instead of just "Rested" since you actually own the bed.

It's definitely the most convenient of the purchasable houses.

Comment: yea, breezehome is the house I use the most despite owning houses in most holds.  If I need to enchant something, I just go to Dragonreach.  The smithy is close by as well.  Also, whiterun is sort of in the middle of everything.

Comment: @yx. Honeyside in Riften could be called better because it's nearly as convenient, has access to the Thieve's Guild, and has an Enchanting table, but I do like to at least pay lip service to in-game convenience, and Whiterun is (as you said) in the middle of everything.

Comment: I also use Breezehome but I usually travel to Dragonsreach and run down, saves the extra load screen of travelling to Whiterun and then running through the main gate. It also means I go past the shop and sell all the stuff I've picked up along the way.

Comment: @ChrisNicholson: extra loading screen? When I fast-travel to Whiterun I actually start *inside* Whiterun so I have exactly one loading screen (when entering the house).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - Well that sucks, I land facing the main gate so the first thing I have to do is run forward one step and enter another loading screen! Maybe I better start a question asking about this :P

Comment: What about spouses? Can you use their house safely?

Comment: @Allov Yes, you can.

Answer (score 2):

Anise's Cabin or the supply chest in front of High Hrothgar provide the most convenient storage in the game. Fast travel directly to them, no loading screens at all. Both are free. Anise's cabin includes an enchanter and alchemy table.

Comment: Are these safe storages? do they never reset?

Comment: @Arperum Yes, Anise's basement is safe storage: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Anise's_Cabin

Answer (score 1):

Best house IMO is Hjerim. I wouldn't get this house until you are at about mid level range. Its the second most expensive house in the game but has more storage and features then the Solitude house that is the most expensive.

Features:
5 book shelves -- 1 four tier and 4 two tier.
7 display cases -- 4 dagger cases and 3 large cases
3 mannequins
9 weapons plaques
Enchant and potion stations
1 weapons rack
1 chest
Extremely well stocked house when all upgrades are purchased.

There are tons of misc shelves and containers to store and display all of your stuff. If you fast travel to Palace Of Kings in Windhelm its just a one load screen and a quick jog to the west of the spawn location. I like this area as the alchemist, blacksmith, and misc booths for selling/buying are all in one location close by. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

A really decent no load after fast travel no load place is folders tooth this is north of the islands to the west of riften there is a quest to wipe the silver hand our of the keep there are 7 boxes in three keep and a loading zone away there its a black Smith inside the keep you can use

The name doesn't come to me  but Another Good place for magic users is a half sunken Temple exactly north and on the other side of the river from the first 3 stones you find this place is filled with the black robe mages a sh*t load of boxes and both an exchanting table as well as a potion table lots of ingrediants here too

Comment: If you put stuff in any of those boxes it will disappear after some time. See http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses#Free_Shacks for the few places in game that aren't houses but have safe containers.

Answer (score 0):

Two places:

- Blades temple: As soon as you travel, chest is right there, no one's around.  It's the best location, because you fast travel right to it, and right back out again. No door, no loading.
- Other place is top of the Throat of the World. The chest there as well, same thing. No loading required.

The only downside I have found with these is no way to separate your stuff. Once it's full, it takes awhile to scroll all the way down.